# Charging Insulators

Tags: charge, conductors, insulators

Can insulators like plastics be charged with the help of conduction? What happens when such materials are brought in contact with charged bodies that might be conductor or insulator?

Answer (score 0):

No , it's not possible to charge insulators by conduction.

If an insulator is brought close to a charged body or vice a versa the atoms of insulator will become elongated kinda like dipole induced forces.